# In ScienceLogic is there a trigger for when a ticket is created?

Tags: web-services, api, soap, hook, ticket-system

I'm looking to see if there is a hook or a trigger that will fire once a ticket has been created in [ScienceLogic](https://www.sciencelogic.com/)

I am using the em7 API for creating tickets, and I need to hook into the after ticket creation action, so I can send an email, or send a SAOP request to ITSM Remedy to generate a ticket in their system.

Answer (score 0):

After looking around everywhere I can think, and asking on the Science Logic Forums, it seems that that is not really anything that I am looking for.  The closest I was able to come up with was a dynamic app emisary, that was scheduled to run once a minute, and run some code.  The code then checks to see if there is a custom note that triggers if it has been seen or not, and then uses that as the trigger to know if it is new.  Not ideal for sure, but it works for my needs.